# How to detect when a ScrollViewer finishes scrolling?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, scrollviewer

BTW I'm using UWP in case it matters.
So I am using a ListView and all ListViews have a ScrollViewer attached to them (in default template) by default. The problem is that I cannot find an event (on the ListView itself or on its ScrollViewer) that triggers when the ListView finishes scrolling.

I used the scrollViewer.ChangeView() method to automatically scroll to the beginning of the ListView and it uses an animation to scroll to the top, so I think that has something to do with it because the ViewChanged event fires before the animation completes. If I am correct about that then there would have to be a way to determine if the animation is complete because I need to be alerted when the ListView is completely idle again, which is only when the scroll animation completes. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wire up the scrollViewer's [ViewChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged), and check the `IsIntermediate` of the event argument.

```
private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsIntermediate)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("scroll ongoing");
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("scroll finish");
    }
}
```

This event is fired multiple times. When the scroll finishes, `IsIntermediate` is false.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Comment: Maybe the system has changed - I'm finding that ViewChanged fires with a false result for e.IsIntermediate() (this is C++/winrt) but the scroll animation has not yet completed.